# Can't run xcodebuild as root

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild

I'm running Xcode 6.4 and trying to build my project using the command line.  This works fine without using sudo:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "project.xcworkspace" -scheme "project"
```

results in Build Succeeded.   However:

```
sudo xcodebuild -workspace "project.xcworkspace" -scheme "project"
```

causes the operation to get stuck.  I do have Xcode 7.0 Beta installed, is there anyway this could be the issue?

Comment: Why are you trying to run xcodebuild as root? Build processes generally shouldn't require that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my schemes were not shared, which caused xcodebuild to get stuck waiting for input

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2949